# why the program is stop working on run-time error"1004" Application-defined or object-defined error on line?

Tags: excel, vba

**why the program does not work?
it stall with error invalid "next" variable reference**

```
Sub RemoveRows5()
     ThisWorkbook.ActiveSheet.Cells.ClearFormats
    Dim n As Long
    lastrow = Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    MsgBox lastrow
For n = lastrow To 1 Step -1
        If InStr(1, ThisWorkbook.ActiveSheet.Cells(n, 1).Text, "<>", vbTextCompare) > 0 Then
            ThisWorkbook.ActiveSheet.Cells(n, 1).EntireRow.Delete
        End If
Next lastrow
    End Sub
```

Comment: At a guess, n = 0?

Comment: n is very large

Comment: how do i stop the program if n =0

Comment: use an if statement

Comment: Use a `For n = lastrow to 1 step -1` loop instead of `Do While`

Comment: how do we remake from do while to for to?

Comment: Exactly how @Rory has suggested. change your `Do While n <= ...` to the `FOR` statement Rory suggested and change `Loop` to `Next`